# Rules for references when inheriting from base class

Tags: c#

Given that Project A is a C# Class Library and that Project B is a console application that has a dependency on Project A.

In Project A the following class is defined:

```
public class ActionMailNotifier : RazorMailerBase
{
        private readonly string _viewPath;
        private readonly EmailHost _emailConfig;
                   ...
                   ...
}
```

"RazorMailBase" is contained in an external dll, ActionMailer.dll, that is referenced by Project A.

In Project B the following class is defined:

```
public class EmailFareMonitorAlertNotifier : ActionMailNotifier
{
                        ...
                        ...
}
```

If ActionMailer.dll is not referenced in Project B the compiler generates an error message indicating that a reference to ActionMailer.dll is required.  Is there a way to structure this such that a reference to the external dll is not required in Project B?

Comment: not sure the question. Are you asking if there is a way to use code from another assembly without referencing it?

Answer (score 1):

No. As long as `EmailFareMonitorAlertNotifier` ultimately derives from assembly `external.dll` you need to reference it so that the compiler and runtime have the information necessary to use the type.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you were to remove all references to any type in Project B that references ActionMailer.dll, you wouldn't see any errors. But since `RazorMailBase` is defined in ActionMailer.dll, you'll have to have that reference to use `ActionMailNotifier`, or any other type derived from a class in the external library.

Answer (score 0):

As an absolute minimum, the Project B will have to refer all the assemblies present in the inheritage hierarchy of its own type `EmailFareMonitorAlertNotifier`, so I guess the answer is no.